# Finite elements $W^{1,\infty}$ error estimates

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, approximation-theory

Are there finite element method setups that provide error estimates in the $W^{1,\infty}$ norm (i.e., bounds on $\|u'_h - u'\|_\infty$)? Which families of elements can be used for implementing them?

Comment: After a few days with little feedback, I have [crossposted](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/18852) on scicomp.stackexchange.

Comment: For what problem?

Comment: @JungWenChen Any problem -- I am just fishing for idea to apply them to a different setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved on [scicomp.se](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/18852/finite-elements-w1-infty-error-estimates) (TL;DR: Chapter 8 of Brenner and Scott's Mathematical Theory of Finite Element Methods, $\|u - u_h\|_{W^1_\infty} \le C h^{k - 1}\|u\|_{W^k_\infty}$).

(I'm posting this to prevent this question from being bumped up because it has no answers).